# Confusing dot product and inner product in a weak formulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, inner-products, finite-element-method, poissons-equation

I have been struggling with this for a while. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method#The_weak_form_of_P2), as you can see, they define the **weak formulation** of the Poisson equation as:

$-\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla v\,ds = \int_{\Omega}fv\,ds \equiv -\phi(u,v)$ (not sure what the $\equiv$ symbol means here(?)), where they specify that the ''." denotes the dot product, $v$ is a test function, $u$ the unknown and $\phi$ an operator (or map). Few lines later; they explain: "Such functions are (weakly) once differentiable and it turns out that the symmetric bilinear map $\phi$ then defines an inner product which turns $H_0^1(0,1)$ into a Hilbert space"

Does this mean that the weak formulation in this case is by default an inner product that uses the dot product?

**EDIT**: I checked this [pdf file](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/FEM17/pdfs/0-19-852868-X.pdf) that studies the weak formulation of **Poisson's equation**, apparently the **weak formulation** defines an inner product.

I just need a confirmation if what I am doing is correct...

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your last sentence but I think you got it. The weak formulation of the Poisson's equation defines a bilinear map $\phi$ which happens to be an inner product over $H_0^1$. Also the use of the sign $\equiv$ is not clear to me as well.

Comment: @nicomezi I've just added an edit to the post, thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: @nicomezi While we are still on it, if you check my question [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009568/difference-between-the-definition-of-the-dot-product-in-infinite-and-finite-dimensions](here), we can safely say that when discretizing the weak formulation the inner product becomes a dot product since my functions are no longer square integrable (all discrete), right?

Comment: The $\equiv$ sign is a (terrible) way to indicate a definition (terrible because $X\equiv Y$ doesn't tell you whether $X$ is defined by $Y$ or $Y$ is defined as $X$ in the abstract).  I'd much prefer $=:$ here.

Comment: @user10354138 I fully agree with you. It's just a copy paste of the Wikipedia definition...

Comment: @nicomezi Not a big inner product but a discretized inner product that becomes a dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is what I am trying to say

Comment: You can probably formulate it this way but again I do not see the point.

Comment: @nicomezi I am just writing a report and I am asked to be as precise and concise as possible. And since it's been a while since my last math class I'm trying my best not to mistake or confuse few defintions.

Comment: I would definitely not write that a discretization would lead to a discrete inner product in this case. Although it seems correct I find this confusing and make a complicated problem apparently simple.

Comment: @nicomezi What do you suggest I write when moving from the continuous form of the weak formulation to a discrete one, when it comes to the definition of the inner product ?

Comment: It depends on what is intended with the discretization of the weak formulation. I guess it is for numerical computations ? In this case I would rather speak about a weighted/rescaled sum (depending on your quadrature rule).

Comment: @nicomezi Understood, thank you so much :)

Comment: $\equiv$ is sometimes used to state not just an equality, but a **definition**, e.g
$$e\equiv \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Comment: @K.defaoite They have not defined it so it really is confusing. Thank you for your remark btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's an inner product is that the inner product axioms are satisfied for $\phi(u,v)=\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla v.$

The easy ones to show are symmetry and linearity, i.e., $\phi(u,v)=\phi(v,u)$ and $\phi(au,v)=a\phi(u,v)$ ($a$ constant). One has to also show that $\phi(u,u)\ge0$ for all $u$, and $\phi(u,u)=0$ if and only if $u=0$.

One has that $\phi(u,u)=\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2\ge0$. Then, if $u=0$, then $\phi(u,u)=\int_\Omega0=0$, and if $\phi(u,u)=0$, then $\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2=0$, and so $u$ must be constant, but also $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, so the constant must in fact be zero, so $u=0$.

Comment: Very precise and concise, thank you so much sir!