# Geometric interpretation of inner product

Tags: inner-products, geometric-interpretation

I already know the geometric interpretation of dot product (the length of projected vector multiply with the other vector's length)

But is there a geometric interpretation for any inner product ?

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476738/difference-between-dot-product-and-inner-product

Comment: $<u,e>e$, for e a unit vector, is the component of u in the direction e. Here u and e might be vectors in $\mathrm{R}^n$ with dot product but might also be functions with an integral inner product.